# How does Bazel interpret special lexemes like `/`, `:`, `//` and `@` in labels?

Tags: bazel

I'm having trouble understanding how to construct proper `label` forms when dealing with external repositories (directories with their own `WORKSPACE`).

What is the semantic meaning of characters like `/`, `:`, `//` or `@`?

For example:

- `@foo/bar`
- `@foo:bar`
- `//foo`
- `foo`

Do they preserve their meaning when used in an external repository? Also, is `//external` special in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`/` is a separator for package and target names.**

- `relative/package/to/my:target`
- `//absolute/package/to:my/file/target.java`

A package is defined as a directory containing a `BUILD` or `BUILD.bazel` file.

**`:` is the lexeme for selecting a rule or file target in a package.**

- `//my/package:my_java_binary`

Selects the target `my_java_binary` defined in `<workspace root>/my/package/BUILD`

- `//my/package:file.go`

Selects the file `<workspace root>/my/package/file.go` if `<workspace root>/my/package/BUILD` exists, and if there's a rule in that BUILD file that references it.

- `//:my/nested/file.txt`

Selects the file `<workspace root>/my/nested/file.txt` if `<workspace root>/BUILD` exists, but not in the `my` and `my/nested` subdirectories.

**`//` is the location of the current or closest parent directory containing a WORKSPACE file.**

Otherwise known as workspace root.

**`@` is used for referencing a repository by its name when used to the left of `//`**

- `@io_bazel_rules_scala//scala:scala.bzl`: look into your WORKSPACE file for a repository named `io_bazel_rules_scala`. Usually defined using `http_archive` or `git_repository`.
- `@//my/package:target`: `@` alone refers to the current workspace.

As of Bazel 0.16.0, `@` can be used in package names.

> Do they preserve their meaning when used in an external repository?

Yes, think of the `@<repository>` syntax as a namespace mechanism.

> Also, is //external special in any way?

Yes, it's used for the [`bind`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#bind) function, which is not recommended anymore. `bind` lets you give a target an alias in `//external`.